# List & Count Appearances

Tags: php, wordpress

What I want to do is list the amount of movies an actor appears in a movie.
I have tried several ways of doing this, but to no avail.

```
<?php foreach (get_terms('actor') as $cat) : ?>

            <div class="col-md-6">

                <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'actor',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'movie',
    )
)
) );
$count = $the_query->found_posts; ?>
<?php echo $cat->name; ?> [<?php echo $count; ?>]
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I have a custom post type movie and custom taxonomy actor.

I know I am close ...

Thanks in advance

Comment: trying some different code...<?php foreach (get_terms('actor') as $cat) : ?>

    <div class="col-md-4">
     
     <?php
     
     get_posts(array(
      
      'post_type' => 'movies',
         
      'tax_query' => array(
        
        array(
            
         'taxonomy' => 'actor',
            
         'field' => 'slug',
         
         'terms' => '$cat',
        
        )
    
      )

     ) );

     $count = $the_query->found_posts; ?>

     <?php echo $cat->name; ?>[<?php echo $count; ?>]

    </div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

Comment: Why you write `'post_type' => 'post'`? Use custom post type i.e `'post_type' => 'movie'`. Also it's better to get all posts in one query instead of different queries for every single `'actor'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<?php
// Change these if necessary. E.g. If taxonomy name is 'actors' and not 'actor'.
$post_type = 'movie';
$taxonomy = 'actor';

foreach ( get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
) ) as $cat) :
?>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type' => $post_type,
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                    'field' => 'term_id',
                    'terms' => $cat->term_id,
                )
            )
        ) );
        $count = $the_query->found_posts; ?>
        <?php echo $cat->name; ?> [<?php echo $count; ?>]
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Sample output:

[image]